# Where to use TABLESAMPLE in a large SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large SQL query that is bringing data into Power BI.

However it is way too much data.

I want to develop the Power BI report with a random sample of data (not top 100 or limit 100 etc.)

So I want to use the `tablesample` method.

It is easy to use with one single import:

```
select * from table
tablesample (5 percent)
```

But what if there are CTEs and multiple joins for example?

Where does `tablesample` go here? Do I have to attach `Tabelsample` to each `FROM` clause?

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    -- Define the first CTE query here
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition1
),
cte2 AS (
    -- Define the second CTE query here
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE condition2
)
SELECT column1, COUNT(column2) AS count
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.id = cte2.id
JOIN table3 ON cte1.id = table3.id
JOIN table4 ON cte2.id = table4.id
GROUP BY column1
```

Note, my real life SQL query is much larger, and I cannot paste it here.

However I did add `tablesample` after the group by clause, and got the error  `Incorrect syntax near 'TABLESAMPLE'`

Comment: TABLESAMPLE can only do "real" tables, not subqueries or CTEs, because it works on the physical storage. the keyword goes like: "FROM TableName TABLESAMPLE (1000 ROWS)" so you have to do something clever to make your joins work. Probably easiest would be to bit TABLESAMPLE and use "SELECT TOP X ... ORDER BY NEWID()"

Comment: that might be heavy because it actually needs to fetch all data for sorting, but at least you don't read so much data

Comment: `TOP` has a `PERCENT` operator you can use to limit the rows to a percentage. `SELECT TOP(5) PERCENT ...`

Comment: @ThomA - but that has to count all the rows in the first place to know what 10% is

Comment: though if the problem to be solved is just qty of data ingested to PowerBi  rather than query performance should work - but a more random distribution could be got by doing a `where` with modulus on`crypt_gen_random` without the need to spool all the rows first

Comment: I guess it depends on the uniquness of the joins. Does each join create more than one row per input row? Or only one?

Comment: @siggemannen The real table has billions of rows. From what I understand, order by newid() is quite expensive as it goes through every row assigning a random ID. Tablesample is faster which is why I am attempting that.

Comment: @ThomA unfortunately that's not useful for developing a dashboard. It would return the top x% of the dataset. So I'd only be developing visuals with January for example. I need a sample throughout all time to develop properly.

Comment: @MartinSmith it has to be a random sample, or close to random. I can't get the top X or top X% chunk of data. I could end up with just data from january. I need a sample of data throughout the whole time period to develop visuals with monthly filters and charts etc. Also there are billions of rows.

Comment: You can address that to Thom. My suggestion was a  where with modulus on `crypt_gen_random`. - e.g. `WHERE CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3)%100 < 5` to give each row a 1 in 5 chance

Comment: @MartinSmith and how would the modulus oncrypt_gen_random work? Where does it go in the query?

Comment: In your case you would probably want `HAVING CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3)%100 < 5` as you have a `GROUP BY` in the final `SELECT` - this is still on the assumption that the problem you are trying to solve is Qty of data ingested to PowerBi ("way too much data")- not query performance